# Heroku rejects my custom buildpack for ruby-on-rails with latex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, latex, buildpack

I need to add the pipeline

```
source file -> latex -> pdf file
```

to a rails app that I am working on and that is deployed at heroku (http://vschool.herokuapp.com).  I've tried following the advice at

```
https://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex
```

and also the further advice on using mutipacks, e.g., doing

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

after creating a file .buildpacks with contents

```
git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
git://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex.git
git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

Here is what happens when I push:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 480 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:vschool.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:vschool.git'
```

After this my app is hosed and I have to do this:

```
$ heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL
```

after which I am returned to a working state.

I must not have understood how to install multiple buildpacks.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Python in your app? Your .buildpacks file includes the Python buildpack.

Comment: Not using python now (thanks for the info!).  The critical need is pdflatex

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `.buildpack` with

```
git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
git://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex.git
```

It seems that Heroku may be searching for a [Python-specific file](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/018e0f31deaa9ad54ea5ed21cffab4a47a3bd43e/bin/detect#L18) (requirements.txt or setup.py) when it is building your app, instead of a Ruby-specific file (the Gemfile).

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. I tried that, but got the same kind of error: 

    `! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

    `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:vschool.git'`

Comment: That error looks like a problem with your git repository. Did you use `git commit --amend`? Has anyone else been working on the server. If it is just you, run `git push heroku master --force` to force update Heroku's copy. If others are pushing code, you should pull in their changes `git pull heroku master` then `git push heroku master`.

Comment: It is just me.  I will try --force.  Thanks!